# Unable to JTAG MEGA2560 R3

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmelstudio, jtag

I am getting the same error I see others have had using a brand new install of "Microchip" Studio 7, with the MKII programmer. I am trying to program a Arduinoish Mega2560 r3 board. If I go into programming using the mkii ISP cable to the r3, I can read voltage, and if I hold down the reset button on the r3, and time it just right, I can read the ID. Otherwise, I just get the fail others have seen saying unable to enter programming mode. What I really want to do is set the JTAGEN fuse so I can use JTAG. But that has the same/similar problem. I can sometimes read the fuses by holding the reset button down and timing it right. JTAGEN and OCD are NOT set. I can get the board(S) (I have multiple with same issue) to program flash with AS7 using the USB cable and avrdude based "external tool". But that is really just using avrdude. It is unclear to me why the mkii connected to the 6pin ISP port, and setup as ISP in the gui, is broken. I can only get it to read using the mkii, with some combination of holding the reset on the r3, and hitting the AS7 gui read button just right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Chip erase over ISP, setup xtal fuses and it should be all

Comment: I do not believe xtal fuses are the issue.  They have not been changed and the board runs.  I can not erase if I cannot connect.

Comment: Important part was chip erase, xtal setting is just it's not running at 8MHz internal clock divided by 8 (DIV8 fuse) - which is default fuses setting

Comment: Still don't think it will do anything w/o connecting first, that includes erase. A brand new Atmel-ICE programmer arrived yesterday.  It works perfectly in ISP mode.  Now that I was able to reset the jtag fuse in ISP mode, I can also use the mkii in jtag mode on the same board.  So I still believe there is a problem with the combination of the mkii/AS7 and ISP mode.  It will not work for me.  My guess is that Microchip is no longer updating  AS7 for use with the mkii programmer.  But that is a guess.

Comment: If you have another board, you can load ArduinoISP and use that. But I never tried to use it from Microchip Studio, always directly from avrdude